# Converting a time to valid format

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium-ide

I am trying to come up with a regex to take the following string: 1:38P and convert it to a valid format for parsing in a date.  I need to

1. Check that the last character is either A or P, and if it is NOT, do nothing to the string.
2. If the last letter is an A or P, then strip out that letter from the string, and prepend a Zero (0) to the string.

Comment: What if you have `11:38P`? Still prepend `0`? And are you aware that this will make `1:38P` and `1:38A` the same time?

Comment: The string i get using a js string function in the case of times that have two digits before the colon will return 5 characters XX:XX(where X's are digits), so that is in a valid format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = "1:38P";
var pat = /^(\d+:\d+)(A|P)$/;
var m = pat.exec(d);
if (m) { console.log('We have our winner' + 0 + m[1]}
```

Comment: This works great for times that are in that format, but fails when  d is something like '12:52' which does not have the A or P because that's the 5 characters returned.

Comment: nevermind, figured out the proper syntax to put in a single line in selenium that code. Works as advertised. Thanks!

Comment: In case someone else had the same issue, here's what I did to clean up the issue. The date format given on the site is "11/27/2012 4:52PM", and I needed to get that into a usable format to parse to verify sorting.  I used the following regex to parse the entire string: 
storeEval |  var n =storedVars['Date1']; n.match(/^([0-9\\d]+)\\/([0-9\\d]+)\\/([0-9\\d]+) ([0-9\\d]+):([0-9\\d]+)(AM|PM)/)   | Test

This gave me an array of: 

1.11/27/2012 12:52AM

2.11

3.27

4.2012

5.12

6.52

7.AM


So I could reference the parts of the array and then concatenate them into a valid format for parsing.